# Google App Engine: Deny access to websites / Disavow backlinks

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, google-app-engine

I deployed my Laravel app to Google App Engine (Standard environment). Someone just copied my project 3 times and didn't change root links on images and because of it I have 100+ backlinks and clones loading images from my website. Is there any way to disavow backlinks in app.yaml file?

This is how I can deny access to websites in .htaccess

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "clone1.com" bad_referer
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "clone2.com" bad_referer
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```

My current app.yaml file

```
runtime: php73

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|txt|svg|xml|ico|woff|woff2))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|txt|svg|xml|ico|woff|woff2)$

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
  
env_variables:
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: *KEY*
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because `.htaccess` and the `app.yaml` are build for different purposes.

The `.htaccess` file can control access to a directory because this file is read on every request. So we can say that the `.htaccess` file is a "gatekeeper" and it can be used to block IP address or bad backlinks as you mentioned.

The `app.yaml` on the other hand has more functions in the app other than to control access to individual resources of the app, and for that reason it is not read on every request, so having the same implementation would not work using `app.yaml` for that.

That being said I believe that  the best solution for the issue you are facing is to change the root links on your image files.